# What could be causing this indent behavior?

Tags: indentation

In Typescript files, when I create `enums` I have a comma at the end of each line.

```js
enum thing {

  first = 'first',
    |     // <--- when I press enter the cursor goes here
}
```

When I `:set shiftwidth=4` I get this -

```js
enum thing {

  first = 'first',
      |     // <--- when I press enter the cursor goes here
}
```

But my goal is to make the cursor to go directly under the first line but when I do `:set shiftwidth=0` I get this -

```
enum thing {

  first = 'first',
    |     // <--- when I press enter the cursor goes here
}
```

What is causing the auto indent at two spaces?

Comment: Please include the output of `:setlocal`

Comment: I can reproduce your problem on Vim 9.0. It looks to me a bug in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/typescript.vim`. Enum should be handled differently than normal statement.